# I'm receiving a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I don't understand the error that i'm getting. I've tried to isolate the displayGrid and the updateGrid on to another txt file without the ValueError functions for the input and it works. But now that i enter it into my real file with the ValueError checking for the inputs, it no longer works.
   What i don't understand is during the first iteration of the displayGrid, the error doesn't show, but when i try to use it again for updating, an error shows on line 87. Here is the full error i get:

> File "C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/111/trial.py", line 87, in displayGrid
>       print("|" + grid[row-1][col-1],end = "")
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Here is my code(for context, i'm making a connect4 game):

```
def play():
        grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_name,p1_char,p2_name,p2_char=getGameSettings()
        displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)
        updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char,p2_char)
        displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)
        updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char,p2_char)
        displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)


def getGameSettings(): 

    #PLAYER 1 NAME
    while True:
        p1_name=input("Enter p1_name: ")
        if len(p1_name) > 15 or p1_name == '': #Validation of input p1_name
            print("Input a valid name. Max of 15 characters only.")
            p1_name=input("Enter p1_name: ")
        else:
            break

    #PLAYER 1 CHARACTER
    while True:
        p1_char=input("Enter p1_character: ")
        if len(p1_char) != 1 or p1_char=='' : #Validation of input p1_character
            print("1 character only.")
            p1_char=input("Enter p1_character: ")
        else:
            break

    #PLAYER 2 NAME
    while True:
        p2_name=input("Enter p2_name: ")
        if len(p2_name) > 15 or p2_name == p1_name or p2_name == '': #Validation of input p2_name
            print("Max of 15 characters only or choose a different name.")
            p2_name=input("Enter p2_name: ")
        else:
            break

    #PLAYER 2 CHARACTER
    while  True:
        p2_char=input("Enter p2_character: ")
        if len(p2_char) != 1 or p2_char == p1_char or p2_char == '': #Validation  of input p2_char
            print("1 character only or choose a different character from player 1")
            p2_char=input("Enter p2_character: ")
        else:
            break

    while True: #VALIDATION OF INPUT OF GRID_WIDTH
        try:
            global grid_height
            grid_height=int(input("Enter grid_height(6-10): "))
        except ValueError: #if input is not the right type()
            print('Ivalid input type. Enter an integer')
            continue
        if grid_height > 10 or grid_height < 6: #to check if input is within accepted values
            print('Height must be less than 11 and greater than 5.')
            continue  
        break


    while True: #VALIDATION OF INPUT OF GRID_WIDTH
        try:
            global grid_width
            grid_width=int(input("Enter grid_width: "))
        except ValueError: #if input is not the right type()
            print('Ivalid input type. Enter an integer')
            continue
        if grid_width > 9 or grid_width < 7: #to check if input is within accepted values
            print('Width must be less than 10 and greater than 6.')
            continue  
        break

    #SETTING UP THE GRID
    grid=[]
    for row in range(grid_height): # FOR ROW
        z =[]
        for col in range(grid_width): # FOR COLUMN
            z.append(" ")
        grid.append(z)

    return grid,grid_width,grid_width,p1_name,p1_char,p2_name,p2_char


def displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width):
    for row in range(grid_height):
        for col in range(grid_width+1):
            print("|" + grid[row-1][col-1],end = "")
        print()
    print(" "+" ".join([str(i) for i in range(1, grid_width+1)]))
    return grid

def updateGrid(grid,p1_char,p2_char,p1_name,p2_name):
    while True:
        try:
            move= int(input('Enter your move: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Plese enter a valid  input.')
        if move < 1:
            print('Please  enter a valid input.')
            continue
        break

    for i in range(1,grid_height+1):
        if grid[grid_height-i][move-2]== " ":
            grid[grid_height-i][move-2]= p1_char
        else:
            if grid[0][move-2] != " ":
                updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char,p2_char)
            else:
                continue
        break

    return grid


#def get_input(player, grids, )
#def isWin():

#def isDraw():

#def play():
#displayGrid()
#updateGrid(grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

Comment: probably `grid[row-1][col-1]` is either `int` or `float`

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf how do i fix it?

Comment: I just added an answer

Comment: You may also want to return the correct things: `return grid,grid_width,grid_width, …`?

Comment: Its fixed! Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in multiple ways. You can convert `grid[row-1][col-1]` to a `str` by:

```
print("|" + str(grid[row-1][col-1]), end="")
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can use an f-string:

```
print(f"|{grid[row-1][col-1]}", end="")
```

If your version of Python is < 3.6, then use `str.format`:

```
print("|{}".format(grid[row-1][col-1]), end="")
```

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Yes, it was! It fixed the error, thank you!

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Oh, sure, i will! Thank you!